# Can I suspend iScroll functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll4

I want to disable the scroll sometimes so I can do multi-touch events in the same area, something like...

```
if event.originalEvent.touches.length is 2 then myScroll.disable()
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
myScroll.disable()
```

Then on touchend

```
myScroll.enable()
```

:)