# IScroll inside IScroll: prevent parent from scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll, nested, iscroll, stoppropagation

I have a `div` with IScroll inside another `div` with IScroll. Whenever I try to make scroll on the child `div`, the parent scrolls too, so it's an awful user experience.

I would like not to get every variable and telling it to disable it temporally, such as in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924250/can-i-suspend-iscroll-functionality), because they are dynamic content and the scrollers are created inside a class - so there are not global variables storing the scroller.

I have visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283119/iscroll-inside-iscroll-nested-iscroll-unexpected-behavior) but whenever I try to catch the `event`, it's `undefined` so it raises an error. It seems that IScroll 5 does not send the event to the handlers, so I cannot write `event.stopPropagation()`, because it does nothing.

I've tried with all the events IScroll provides, and even I have tried to switch back to iScroll 4 and trying `onBeforeScrollStart` and so on, also without luck.

The solution should be able to work on **touch enabled devices**, but also with **mouse interaction (drag) and mousewheel**.

Is it possible? If so, what can I do so **the parent scroller stops from scrolling** if it's the child who is getting the scroll action?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try JRoll, it has a method `call`, `call` can switch current scroll instance. Inside `div` switch to outside `div`, you don't use `e.preventDefault` or `e.stopProgapation`. Here has a demo http://www.chjtx.com/JRoll/demos/5.html